# How to manage users who didnt give email in their facebook account?

Tags: php, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook js sdk and php sdk to implement signin with facebook option. I can save facebook user id and email to database and use that to recognize user next time he sign in from facebook. But the prob is that, some users are signed up to facebook with their mobile number and havent added email yet. What can i do in their case?

I need email to implement forgot password option. Does anyone know a work around for users who dont have email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i used it before i was using their facebook unique_ID as the primary key and made the email optional. 
And then time to time i popped my users a notification saying, "You do not have an email, do you want to insert a new one? ".

I guess there is no other workaround since the user can make the email private.